# How to reply review in facebook using API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Does someone know how to reply a review using API facebook, I have the id of the review and i don't know how to post the reply?
I have seen it in other question:
field=open_graph_story is the option available to get the object contains public reviews and id. to retrieve : {page-id}/ratings?field=open_graph_story to post :(POST) {object-id}/comments

I don't know how to exploite it

Thank you for your reply

Comment: I don’t think you can reply to those via API.

Comment: Ok thank you for your reply and how about it "{page-id}/ratings?field=open_graph_story to post :(POST) {object-id}/comments"

Comment: What about it ...?

Comment: about the reply, I found the solution you put the id of the review and you use the API send post

Comment: add your solution as an answer and accept it

Comment: did you find the solution @user3323940